# segmentation error in the fseek line in c code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation error, and have narrowed it down to one line (it's the "fseek" line in the code below-- I commented everything below it out and still got the error but don't get it when I comment out that line.) Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *f_in, *f_out;
    f_in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    fseek(f_in, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return 0
}
```

All the other code seems fine so I didn't include it. I have tried adding a line before the fseek line: "fseek(f_in, 0, SEEK_END);". I have also tried changing the 0 to other numbers, and doing an fread before the fseek, but consistently get the segmentation fault. Does anyone know what is wrong with that line (or a different line, if it's not actually that line)?

Comment: 2 obvious issues: 1-you don't check `argc` to be sure there is an `argv[1]`. 2 - you don't check the result of `fopen()` before you go off and try to use it. Fix those and get back to us...

Comment: you do know that immediately after a call to fopen, the file pointer is at the first character in the file.  so there is no need for a call to fseek() to be at the first char of the file.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Well since the fseek was causing the problem and I don't actually need it, that solves the segmentation error, thank you :)

Comment: (@John3136, yes, I realize that. I didn't include those parts on purpose because while it's good coding practice to include them, they were unrelated to the error on which I was focusing. Otherwise good suggestions though, thanks)

Answer (score 2):

Check if the call to `fopen()` failed:

```
f_in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
if ( NULL == f_in )
{
    // handle error
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the actual code checks argc before accessing argv[] and that an appropriate 'usage' message is displayed if no parameter is present.

It is necessary to check the returned value from fopen (and fseek) to assure the operation was successful.

If this code is failing on the fseek() the it is almost a certainty that the fopen failed.

Resulting in f_in containing NULL rather than a valid pointer to a file descriptor object.